# How to open and close square box animation using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to animate square div open from top. I try some to close that box. its working. But how to do opposite of that.now I want to open it from top to bottom.I used showBox function for opening div from top to bottom.I thing I am going wrong somewhre.

I am very new in this.I want to do animation.you check that box in this link.I am facing while opening it.
    https://dribbble.com/shots/1375652-Gif-Animation-Abracadabra-App.
can you guide me please.

here is my code

```js
function showBox() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#slide1").show();
    //$("#slide1").addClass("transitionIn");
    setTimeout(function() {
      // $("#slide1").removeClass("transitionIn");
      $("#slide1").addClass("transitionIn");
    }, 300)
    `enter code here`
  }, 500);
}
showBox();
```

```css
.transitionIn {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="view" id="slide1">Message</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML code also.

Comment: can you provide your actual code for this. so that we will get clear idea

Comment: https://github.com/sardarminal25/Box     .there is my code u can check it

Comment: please help me.